# Как отобразить в grid layout все изображения на устройстве?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, gridlayoutmanager

Всем привет, есть такой таск - отобразить все изображения хранящиеся в Android устройстве в Grid Layout.
Язык Java.

Answer (score 1):

Декомпозируйте задачи как минимум на 4 части:

1. Вывести `GridLayout` на экран
2. Заполнить клеточки одинаковыми изображениями
3. Считать все изображения которые хранятся в устройстве
4. Собрать все в кучу и все заработает

P.S. и да, такие вопросы как у вас - без строчки кода - здесь не приветствуются. Можно нарваться на грубость.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не хотел никого обидеть, а за ответ спасибо)